# Incompatible type when overriding onCreateDialog()

Tags: android, scala, compiler-errors

I am attempting to create an Android application using Scala 2.9.2. So far, I have got everything to compile.

However, I am running into problems when I perform the following in my activity:

```
override def onCreateDialog(id: Int) {
```

The compiler complains of an incompatible type as `Activity.onCreateDialog()` takes a primitive `int` yet I am passing a `scala.Int`.

The folowing is the compilation error:

```
error: overriding method onCreateDialog in class Activity of type (x$1: Int)android.app.Dialog;
[INFO]  method onCreateDialog has incompatible type
[INFO]   override def onCreateDialog(id: Int) {
[INFO]                ^
[ERROR] one error found
```

I thought these would be compatible.

Can anyone advise how to get around this problem?

Comment: Scala version would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know Scala, but in general such a conversion would be fine when invoking a method, but when *overriding* you must match the signature exactly. (You can easily convert to whatever integer type you choose with a variable assignment at the beginning of your method.)

Comment: @pedrofurla edited to add Scala 2.9.2

Comment: @JeremyRoman Not sure how to do this, seeing as Scala doesn't support a primitive int type

Comment: Can you paste the text of the actual compiler error?

Comment: @JeremyRoman Have pasted now

Comment: Do you return a value of type `android.app.Dialog`? You haven't explicitly given the return type; is the method body such that Scala can infer this return type (or a narrower one, as of JDK 5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is for Scala 2.10, but I *think* that the cause of the error is exactly the same for Scala 2.9.x.

By the way, the `onCreateDialog(int)` method from the type `Activity` is deprecated, but it's beside the point.

Now, I'm not a Scala expert by any means, but from what I have noticed, functions that do not return anything tend do look like `def fun(arg) {}`, and ones that do: `def fun(arg) = {}`. Notice the **=**. You can also spell out the return type if you want.

So I tried to override the method you mention, and here's the (trivial) implementation:

```
override def onCreateDialog(id : Int) = {
    super.onCreateDialog(id)
}
```

And it compiles and runs just fine. When you remove the **=**, you'll get the error you have right now:

> overriding method `onCreateDialog` in class `Activity` of type `(x$1: Int)android.app.Dialog;` method `onCreateDialog` has 
>        incompatible type

The whole `MainActivity`:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    override def onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity)
    }

    override def onCreateDialog(id : Int) = {
        super.onCreateDialog(id)
    }   
}
```

*Notes: I'm using ADT with bundled Eclipse (Juno), created a default Android project, including Scala-IDE (Scala nature) and AndroidProguardScala (AndroidProguardScala nature)*